# Space problem with Sandisk 32 GB flash drive

Tags: usb

When I try to copy an 8 GB video file (.mov) from the **Files** -> **Downloads** directory to a Sandisk jumpdrive with 31 GB of free space on it (after emptying all trash), the copy stops at about 4 GB and eventually times out with the error message

> Error splicing file: File too large.

Not sure if this a driver problem or something else. Any suggested solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Your flash drive is likely formatted in FAT32 format. This format has a maximum filesize of 4GB. If possible, I would recommend reformatting the flash drive in a "large filesize friendly" format, such as NTFS or exFat.

However, note that if you were planning on plugging this flash drive into a TV or receiver or Blu-ray player, the resulting device may not recognize it. Many devices, from my experience, do not recognize NTFS or exFat.

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/440509/getting-around-the-fat32-4gb-file-size-limit/757901) for more detailed information and suggestions at a work around, such as a streaming, networked solution. If that's not an option you could look into splitting the .mov into two (or more) separate .mov's or reducing the quality of your .mov so that it fits into a ~4GB filesize.

Answer (score 1):

**Another Option**

Perhaps reducing the size of the video file is an option.

ffmpeg is the tool.

Manual: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html

Quick Start: https://opensource.com/article/17/6/ffmpeg-convert-media-file-formats

To find original parameters, right click the original video file then click Audio/Video.

There are several ways to reduce file size:

- Basic command is similar to: `ffmpeg -i "input.mov" -c:a copy -c:v copy "output.mkv"`
- Convert to a higher compression Codec: ffmpeg -i "input.mov" -c:a copy **-c:v vp9** "output.mkv"
- Reduce Bitrate, (Kbps): ffmpeg -i "input.mov" -c:a copy **-b:v 500k** "output.mov"
- Reduce Frame Size (WxH in pixels): ffmpeg -i "input.mov" -c:a copy **-s 960x540** "output.mov"
- Reduce Frame Rate (frames / second): ffmpeg -i "input.mov" -c:a copy **-r 30** "output.mov"
- Or some combination of the above.

However you should confirm for your requirements.

The conversion may take some time.

Comment: I did reformat the SanDisk using NTFS and that solved the problem.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @WilliamSeeley Please don't post "thank you" but [accept the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) that solved your problem

Comment: @Fabby Looks to me like there are two answers that give the same solution. Which should William choose the first read or the simplest:?

Answer (score 0):

formatting the disk into EXFat or NTFS and a format will fix the issue.
The problem is caused by the fact that FAT32 only supports files of sizes upto 4gb(single file)

Comment: That's an exact duplicate of the existing answer...